# How to use consumer electronics for industrial application on high temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, consumer-electronics, microelectronics

I need to measure the width of a bar made out of glowing red steel (900-1200 degrees Celsius) using computer vision.

In order to ensure resolution of a 0.5 millimeters/px, the camera is needed to have enough pixels and, considering the field-of-view, to be at a certain distance from the bar.

Can anybody think of a way to use a camera at a distance of 0.5m from the glowing hot bar? Air refrigeration? Refractory enclosure?

Let's talk about it?

Comment: Are you sure its just not cheaper and more  accurate to get a telecentric lens and put it further? Also seems to me that you have made a premature decission for method used

Comment: Insulated enclosure with fireproof glass window, air-cooled. Additional bonus: easy to install a dim filter to reduce glare from the glowing steel, which is bound to confuse the camera.

Comment: Use the glass used in welding goggles - some are available as flat sheets about 2.5" by 4"...

Comment: thank you all for the replies.

@joojaa , the computer vision method was chosen before i had my hands on the project. As an engineer I just gotta make it work. Excelent tip about the telecentric lens, though. I will do some research about the application. Thank you very much for the reply.

Comment: @SF.
we thought about air-cooled enclosures, but had not thought about the fireproof glass. I will do some measuring on the temperatures and design some sketches. Thank you guys.

Comment: Yeah but why the spcific camera

Answer (score 1):

Do you need a single camera, or could you build a precision mount with 2 smaller cameras, each covering one end of the bar?  Saves you a ton of pixels.  Or, for that matter, a single camera with an external  set of path-folding mirrors & prisms so that what the camera "sees" is just the ends of the bars.  This is a common approach taken in various laboratory work when only two small non-adjacent regions are of interest.